# cannot return reference to temporary value error in iterator reduce

Tags: rust

I'm trying to calculate the total of elements using a reducer.

```rust
// map: Map<(i8, i8), u8>
// row: Vec<u8>

row.push(
    *map
    .values()
    .reduce(|acc, curr| &(acc + curr))
    .unwrap_or(&0u8)
);
```

I get following compile error.

```rust
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
   --> src/main.rs:173:46
    |
173 |                         .reduce(|acc, curr| &(acc + curr))
    |                                              ^-------------
    |                                              ||
    |                                              |temporary value created here
    |                                              returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

Here, `reduce` is expecting `&u8` but it can not be changed to a reference because it is a temporary value. How to resolve this?

Comment: The answer provides a solution. Note in addition that Rust not having garbage collection places severee limits on the use of references - in particular, they must not outlive the object they refer to. `&0u8` is super convenient because the compiler places a `0u8` in the executable (without extra cost because it has to do so for all constants anyway) and creates a reference to it that may last for as long as you like. However, a reference to a local variable such as `&acc`, or a reference to the value returned by `+`, can never be returned from the function it appears in, only passed downward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generic solution would be to map the elements from reference to concrete values, which is possible and cheap here:

```rust
row.push(
    map
        .values()
        .copied() // shortcut for .map(|&v| v)
        .reduce(|acc, curr| (acc + curr))
        .unwrap_or(0)
);
```

But a cleaner solution would be to avoid `reduce`, which builds a result the type of the elements it receives, but to use [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold):

```
row.push(
    map
        .values()
        .fold(0, |acc, &curr| (acc + curr))
);
```

This also lets you avoid the `unwrap_or` by using the initial value when the map is empty.

Until now, I was assuming you have a more complex computation than the one you show. If it's not the case, then just use [`sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html#tymethod.sum):

```
row.push(map.values().sum());
```

Comment: It is worth noting that that `map(|&v| v)` is already in std as [`Iterator::copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied).

Comment: Thanks @rodrigo. Edited. I knew about it but I never manage to find the name... I always try `owned` for some reason.